# Is it possible to stream an RTSP feed to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, video, streaming

A co-worker of mine wants to stream an RTSP streaming video feed to his iphone so he can tap into his child's daycare center here and there. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm reasonably experienced with RTSP. From the POV of my iPad, [VLC](https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/vlc-media-player/id650377962) displays our (live) streams perfectly... and for free.

I hate bouncing my iOS users to the "Get VLC to view this content" deal, but it's my least objectionable alternative, for now.

Answer (score 2):

IP Vision is an expensive app. There are several free apps that will stream RTSP on iPhone. I use Aceplayer, but it doesn't seem to be very stable. It may not be the app - I haven't had time to thoroughly test it yet.

There are at least dozen more, so search the app store for RTSP and try out what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be be accomplished with the app [IP Vision](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ip-vision/id300593485?mt=8) from the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Streamie is an app for iPhone, iPad and Apple TV. It also works with Apple Silicon Macs. It’s free to use with one camera. RTSP streaming is its core feature.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/streamie/id1420209171
https://streamie.co

Answer (score -2):

follow this link this will help you :- https://github.com/teocci/RTSP-Client-iOS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.